# How do I enable SQLite3 on FreeBSD?

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony1, freebsd

I have a FreeBSD machine already running PHP 5. I'm trying to get Symfony to work but it requires either pdo_sqlite or sqlite3.

If I type on the command line "sqlite3 --version" it outputs 3.7.5

If I edit my php.ini and uncomment any of the sqlite dll's PHP gives me an error about unknown dll's. I went to sqlite's site and downloaded the sqlite3.dll and tried loading the sqlite3.dll extension but it failed with "Unable to load dynamic library".

At this point I'm really not sure what to do.

Comment: FreeBSD doesn't understand what a dll is, you'll need to update your PHP settings to use the SQLite binaries for FreeBSD.

Comment: ahh right. If I download the source and compile it I get sqlite3.o but don't I need an .so? I'm not sure how to go about getting the shared object.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you need to install databases/php5-pdo_sqlite port and configure your PHP accordingly.

Comment: How precisely does one do that?

Comment: To install port you should have ports tree (/usr/ports) first. If you do, run `make -C /usr/ports/databases/php5-pdo_sqlite install clean`. As for configuring PHP, i can't help with that, sorry.

Comment: It wasn't an answer, and it didn't even come close to answering it. With an appropriate edit I could be convinced to upvote it instead. Funny how those stackexchange sites work, eh?

Comment: trollexchange* fix'd that for you.